# qemu-system-i386: -sdl: SDL support is disabled ( ubuntu 19.04 )

Tags: 19.04, qemu

i'm working in a project that, after compiling it, i have to launch with qemu.

When i type `make qemu` i have this error. I've search but i'm unable to find an answer.

I have install qemu with `sudo apt install qemu-system-i386`

Any helps?

Answer (score 6):

SDL was becoming more and more unsupportable. The old 1.2 got out of date and many projects had various bugs adopting the newer 2.0 (that happened to QEMU).

So after Ubuntu 18.04 Ubuntu (and Debian) we switched away from it. These days SDL isn't even in [main](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#The_Four_Main_Repositories) anymore. The alternative graphical backend - that also mostly works much better and gets more usage/fixes is GTK.

Use:
`qemu-... -display gtk`

Comment: seems not to work

Comment: Any more details than that to further help you?

Comment: fix with commeting this line SET(EMULATOR_FLAGS ${EMULATOR_FLAGS} -sdl) in cmakelist

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can compile qemu-system-i386 with forced SDL support by doing:

```
./configure --enable-sdl --with-sdlabi=2.0
make
```